# How do I turn off autolist in tcsh terminal

Tags: command-line, tcsh

Since I upgraded to Trusty Tahr, whenever I do tab completion in the (tcsh) terminal it will complete as far as it can and then show me all of the options available.  I hate this behavior and want it to stop.  If I want the options I can just hit ^D.  I've figured out that this is likely due to the 'autolist' environment variable, but I have not set it to be on, and I can't figure out how to turn it off. 'set autolist=false' doesn't work, neither does 'no', '0', 'off', or anything else I could think of. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `unset autolist`.

Using `set autolist=false` will actually *set* the variable; since `tcsh` just checks if the variable is defined (the value can be anything from empty, to `false`, to `42`, etc).